# How do you configure the subject naming strategy for Confluent Schema Registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using Confluent Schema Registry with Avro and I'd like to use multiple schemas in one Kafka Topic.

The default subject naming strategy `TopicNameStrategy` does not allow for this because it couples the schema subject name to the topic name. It is apparently possible to override this and set the subject naming strategy to `RecordNameStrategy` or `TopicRecordNameStrategy`.

Unfortunately, the documentation is not very clear on how or where the subject naming strategy can be overridden.

This [document](https://docs.confluent.io/6.0.0/schema-registry/schema-validation.html#change-the-subject-naming-strategy-for-a-topic) suggests that you can provide the configuration when creating or modifying a topic:

> Starting with Confluent Platform 5.5.0, the naming strategy is associated with the topics. Therefore, you now have the option to configure a naming strategy to something other than the default on a per-topic basis for both the schema subject key and value with `confluent.key.subject.name.strategy` and `confluent.value.subject.name.strategy`.
>
> From the Confluent CLI, use the `--config` option to create or modify a topic with the specified naming strategy. For example:
>
> To create a topic that uses RecordNameStrategy for the value:
>
> ```
> ./bin/kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
> --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic my-other-cool-topic \
> --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true --config confluent.value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
> ```

When I try this, the `kafka-topics` application returns the following error:

```
Error while executing topic command : Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.subject.name.strategy
[2020-10-31 10:17:00,947] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Unknown topic config name: confluent.value.subject.name.strategy
 (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)
```

I've also tried configuring the subject name strategy when writing records to Kafka using `kafka-avro-console-producer` via property `value.subject.name.strategy` as this [document](https://docs.confluent.io/6.0.0/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#configuration-details) suggests. However, the console producer ignores this property and creates a new subject for the topic using the default strategy.

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
    --broker-list kafka-broker-0.kafka-broker:9092 \
    --property schema.registry.url='http://kafka-schema-registry:8081' \
    --property value.schema='<MYSCHEMA>' \
    --property value.subject.name.strategy='io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy' \
    --topic mytopic
```

Apparently there used to be a way to configure the strategy on the broker itself, but I can't find any documentation states how to do that either.

What is the correct way to configure the naming strategy? Where should it be configured -- on the topic, on the topic producer (`kafka-avro-console-producer` in this case), or somewhere else?

Additional context:

- I'm running everything in Docker using images `confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.0.0`, `confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.0.0`, and `confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0`
- The `kafka-topics` and `kafka-avro-console-producer` versions are also set to `6.0.0`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

kafka-avro-console-producer doesn't support to specify the naming strategy yet. You can use other tool like zoe: https://adevinta.github.io/zoe/advanced/avro/

It's something you can define in the producer as property (key.subject.name.strategy and value.subject.name.strategy). You can choose one of the existing strategies or develop your own.

Comment: Confluent Platform 6.1.0 is out and kafka-avro-console-producer now supports the naming strategy.

However, I also found that you need to configure your connector to use the alternate naming strategy (`key.converter.key.subject.name.strategy` & `value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy`).

Comment: What do you mean doesn't support? Console tools support any producer or consumer property. Also, those are serializer properties, not client properties

Answer (score 1):

You can submit the naming strategy while running the producer from the console.

```
kafka-avro-console-producer \
--bootstrap-server bootstrap-server-url:port \
--topic my-kafka-topic \
--property key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy  \
--property value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy \
--property schema.registry.url=https://schemaregistryurl:port \
--producer.config <locationOfTheConfig> \
--property value.schema='{ \"namespace\": \"com.demo.user\", \"name\": \"UserCreatedEvent\", \"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"username\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"phone\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"age\",\"type\":\"int\"}]}' \
--property parse.key=true \
--property key.schema='{\r\n  \"name\": \"UserCreatedEventKey\",\r\n  \"type\": \"record\",\r\n  \"doc\": \"Key for user creation event,\r\n  \"namespace\": \"com.demo.user\",\r\n  \"fields\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"name\": \"userId\",\r\n      \"type\": \"string\",\r\n      \"doc\": \"Unique identifier for the user\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}' \
--property key.separator=" " \
--property basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO \
--property basic.auth.user.info= username:password
```

As you can see we are overriding the default name strategy for both Key and Value by providing

```
--property key.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy  \
--property value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy \
```

This will generate the schema under the subject names

```
my-kafka-topic-com.demo.UserCreatedEventKey for key schema and
my-kafka-topic-com.demo.UserCreatedEvent for value schema
```

These schemas can be seen at the `https://schemaregistryurl:port/schemas`